# loop through associative array key

Tags: php

I want to loop through an associate array.

```
foreach($details as $key=>$value){
echo  $details['image1'];
}
```

Above code works fine.

What i want if i can replace the 1 in `$details['image1']` to 2,3,4 ..etc
what  i tried

```
$j=i;
foreach($details as $key=>$value){
echo  $details['image.$j'];
$j++;
}
```

But it does not work.
It there a way to dynamically change the key of associate array.
like

```
'$details['image2'];
$details['image3'];'
```

Comment: because it takes $i as literal not as variable

Comment: I don't know how you create `$details` array, but you probably want to make an array of images instead of this mess. `$details = ['images' => ['image1', 'image2', ...]];`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of iterating over the keys of an array if the foreach body recreates different keys anyways. It almost looks like what you want to do is `foreach($details as $key=>$value) { echo  $value; }`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The actual code is some thing like this <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id1"/>
  `<label for="id1">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/userimage/<?php echo $details['image_path1']?>" width="100"/>
  </label>`  I have to dynamicaly load database pictures and show it in slider.

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quote mark

```
$j=i;
foreach($details as $key=>$value){
   echo  $details["image{$j}"];
   $j++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it

```
$j = $i;
$newArray = [];
foreach ($details as $key => $value) {
    $newArray['image'. $j] = $value;
    $j++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `echo  $details['image.$j'];` $j is inserted as a literal.

You can either use

1. `echo  $details['image'.$j];` or
2. `echo  $details["image{$j}"];`

to correctly concat.

Although you actually do not need a foreach loop using this syntax. A simple for-loop would be sufficient.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($details); $i++)
{
  echo  $details["image.{$i}"];
}
```

Using foreach you probably do not need to count up $i ... but that depends on your array.

Have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php